# Close db connection before terminating

Tags: node.js, node-mongodb-native

When I'm debugging I start and terminate my node process a bunch of times. That makes this happen:

```
2014-07-20T15:53:19.162-0400 [conn352]  authenticate db
2014-07-20T15:53:19.163-0400 [conn353]  authenticate db
2014-07-20T16:13:59.631-0400 [conn354]  authenticate db
2014-07-20T16:13:59.635-0400 [conn355]  authenticate db
2014-07-20T16:13:59.636-0400 [conn356]  authenticate db
2014-07-20T16:13:59.636-0400 [conn357]  authenticate db
2014-07-20T16:19:01.747-0400 [conn358]  authenticate db
2014-07-20T16:19:01.750-0400 [conn359]  authenticate db
2014-07-20T16:19:01.751-0400 [conn360]  authenticate db
2014-07-20T16:19:01.767-0400 [conn361]  authenticate db
2014-07-20T16:19:33.227-0400 [conn362]  authenticate db
2014-07-20T16:19:33.229-0400 [conn363]  authenticate db
2014-07-20T16:19:33.230-0400 [conn364]  authenticate db
2014-07-20T16:19:33.239-0400 [conn365]  authenticate db
2014-07-20T17:04:08.577-0400 [conn366]  authenticate db
2014-07-20T17:04:08.579-0400 [conn367]  authenticate db
2014-07-20T17:04:08.580-0400 [conn368]  authenticate db
2014-07-20T17:04:08.580-0400 [conn369]  authenticate db
2014-07-20T17:05:15.783-0400 [conn370]  authenticate db
2014-07-20T17:05:15.785-0400 [conn371]  authenticate db
```

How can I close the mongodb connection (`db.close()`) before terminating the node process? Is there some way to add an event listener like `beforeunload` in client-side JS? Or do I have to configure a db option to automatically do that?

Comment: That looks more like creating new session that starting/stopping node.  Unless you are authenticating the user/client against mongo, you probably want to move out the db connection initialization from the session initialization logic.  Do it once for the live of the server rather than once per session.

Comment: @dc5 No, it's starting and stopping node. I just do it a lot :P

Comment: FYI, the mongodb socket is managed by the client (i.e. your node driver), if the process is terminated, so is that socket. The open connection to mongod/mongos will automatically close in time (how soon is dependent on the OS). See https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mongodb-user/IdSp7WcA66o/1eytPh2z2WIJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen for the ['exit' event](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_exit) on `process`, but you can't execute anything asynchronous in there because nothing inside your 'exit' handler can/will keep the process open.

What you should do instead of forcefully exiting your process is to let it exit naturally by closing any open connections, servers, etc.